# How to compare only (Y-m-d) in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In my Mysql database i have a field named "time" which includes the mysql 
timestamp `(Y-m-d H:i:m)`. 
Now, i would like to check if there a value in my table, which is from today. 
The time does not matter.

My query until now:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE time => '".$date."' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Tip : wrap time with `\``

Comment: There's no `=>` comparison operator. ITYM `>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date()` in MYSQL extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression 'timestampfield'.

Syntax:

```
DATE(timestampfield)
```

So try with the following query:

```
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) = '$date' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysql function DATE() to compare date only.

```
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) >= '".$date."' LIMIT 1");
```

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to convert both items in date format to compare dates not strings:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) => DATE('".$date."') LIMIT 1");
```

Also, consider using [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) although here is not a case for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

try [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)  and also you are using comparison operator in wrong way use `>=` instead of `=>`

```
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) >= '$date' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) >= '".$date."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$select = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(time) ='".$date."' LIMIT 1");
```

no need of less than or geater than because he is looking for current date only.